# Tumblr: automatically list all pages

Tags: html, tumblr

I've had a [tumblr](http://tumblr.com) account for a while and currently have an outdated theme. I was trying to update the theme to automatically list all pages but couldn't find a way to do this. Am I missing something?

I couldn't find a tag in their [docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) to loop though and list pages. In theory something like this would work but I'd need to loop though and get all the pages first.

```
 {block:HasPages} 
       <a href="{URL}"> {Label}</a>
 {/block:HasPages}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with

```
 {block:HasPages} 
      {block:Pages}
       <a href="{URL}"> {Label}</a>
       {/block:Pages}
 {/block:HasPages}
```

?

Comment: No, but that semed to do it. Thanks.